# Set names for list of data frame in Python

Tags: python

I read multiple files in directory

```
files = sorted(glob("df*.csv"))    
dfList = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]
print(files)

['df.csv', 'df08.csv', 'df1.csv', 'df2csv.csv', 'df3.csv', 'dfcsv.csv', 'dfcsv_withsep.csv']
```

I want to set the old name for each dataset in dfList, so I try to loop

```
names = ['df.csv', 'df08.csv', 'df1.csv', 'df2csv.csv', 'df3.csv', 'dfcsv.csv', 'dfcsv_withsep.csv']
list_names = [i.split(".")[0] for i in names]
print(list_names)

['df', 'df08', 'df1', 'df2csv', 'df3', 'dfcsv', 'dfcsv_withsep']

for i in list_names:
    for j in dfList:
        i = pd.DataFrame(j)
```

It doesn't work, if I do manually, it works.

```
df = dfList[0]
df08 = dfList[1]
df1 = dfList[2]
```

Do I do something wrong?

Comment: I think I got what I want `pe1 = ','.join(list_names)`
`pe1 = [pd.DataFrame(i) for i in dfList]`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing in your for loop. You're just assigning local variable `i` that has no impact on any result. You need to store result you want into something that you can use, something like:

```
names = ['df.csv', 'df08.csv', 'df1.csv', 'df2csv.csv', 'df3.csv', 'dfcsv.csv', 'dfcsv_withsep.csv']
list_names = [i.split(".")[0] for i in names]
new_names = dict()
for i in list_names:
    for j in dfList:
        new_names[i]=pd.DataFrame(j)
```

or something similar.

Comment: if I do that, I can access dataframe by  new_names["df"], not df